# Modx комментарии

Tags: modx

Подскажите как правильно реализовать отзывы на сайте. Обычная пустая страница, где требуется ввести имя, почту и сообщение и оно тут же появляется на странице. Что то похожее на постоянный чат.

tickets не советовать

Answer (score 2):

Информации маловато для того, чтобы дать полноценный ответ. Но, если я правильно понял, можно сделать форму с необходимыми полями, например, с помощью FormIt или лучше сразу на AjaxForm. Далее написать сниппет, который будет получать данные из формы и записывать их в ресурс в админке и прицепим хуком этот сниппет к ajaxForm. Примерно это выглядит так:
Вызов ajaxForm:

```
[[!AjaxForm@ajaxForm?
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`FormForReviews`
    &hooks=`spam,reviewSnippet`
    &validate=`name:required, email:email:required, text:required:stripTags`
    &validationErrorMessage=`В форме имеются ошибки!`
    &successMessage=`Сообщение отправлено`
]]
```

Сам сниппет:

```
$name = $hook->getValue('name');
$email = $hook->getValue('email');
$text = $hook->getValue('text');

$review = $modx->newObject( 'modResource' );
$review->fromArray(
    array(
        'pagetitle' => "Новый отзыв от ".$name." от " . date("d.m.Y - H:i"),  //название страницы
        'parent'    => $scriptProperties['parent'], // id родителя
        'published' => 0,   //Опубликован, по умолчанию - нет
        'publishedon' => time(), //дата
        'show_in_tree' => 1,
        'hidemenu' => 1,
        'searchable' => 0,
        'template' => 14, //id шаблона
    )
);
$review->save(); //сохраняем

$review->setTVValue('rev-name', $name);
$review->setTVValue('rev-email', $email);
$review->setTVValue('rev-text', $text);
```

Надо создать 3 доп поля для данных:
rev-name - Имя, 
rev-email - е маил, 
rev-text - текст отзыва (тип textarea)

Создаем ресурс куда будут сыпаться отзывы и его id приписываем в сниппет. Если хотите, чтобы отзыв сразу появлялся то в сниппете пишете 'published' => 1

Можно добавить еще доп поле типа textarea типа ответ администратора и выводить его если оно заполнено по типу [[*admin-answer:ne=``:then=`[[*admin-answer]]`]]

Лучше это все запихать в Коллекцию (модуль такой, позволяющий удобной правлять ресурсами), но тогда в сниппете указать 'show_in_tree' => 0`

В том ресурсе, который мы создали для отзывов нужно будет сделать вызов pdoPage с выводом всех отзывов на этой странице.